# Ionic: What css prefixes do I need to cover? (-webkit, -moz, -ms)

Tags: css, ionic-framework, webkit

Which ones does ionic need to cover all it's bases? Intuition tells me it should only need -webkit

Comment: You question is not clear, can you explain a bit more